# Code to display all exported functions by a shared library in Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to write an **Android application** that is able to display **list of exported functions by a  shared library (.so)**.

`nm/objdump/readelf` tool is only available for Windows/Linux. So I have thought about compiling **[platfor_external_elfutils](https://github.com/android/platform_external_elfutils)** to get a toolchain with `nm` or `objdump` tool.

However, this is not a good solution considering the big dependencies the `toolchain` may cause (can be up to xx MB).

I want to ask if there is any available simple code to achieve the purpose without having to compile and attache the whole `toolchain` in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably too late for the original poster, but libelf can be built as a static library (libelf.a) from Android sources, at least since JB4.2. Just use

```
make libelf
```

In the main directory to build it.

If someone knows how to build it as a dynamic library/shared object that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use libelf library (from [elftoolchain](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/) - it's BSD licensed) to parse the binary. libelf comes with source for [elfdump](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/elftoolchain/browser/trunk/elfdump) utility that dumps various information about ELF file including export list. Just strip out the source you don't need and you're ready. Executable for this won't take more than 100KB.

Comment: How do I compile it for Android? I have tried importing the source code to Android project. There are too many errors, so I couldn't compile it.